# Search in multiple fields in ElasticSearch returns more results than expected

Tags: elasticsearch, match

I'm trying to perform a search by country, or city or both using ElasticSearch.

When I perform a search by country using `USA` as the search term, I get these results, which are correct.

| email | country | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mike@example.com | USA | Portland |
| You Can Also | USA | Chicago |

The query looks like so:

```
{
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "country": {
                      "query": "USA",
                      "operator": "and"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I want to also search by city using the term `Portland` I'm expecting to get only one result

| email | country | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mike@example.com | USA | Portland |

but I get both results again, just like when I'm only searching by country.

The query for both fields looks like this:

```
{
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "country": {
                      "query": "USA",
                      "operator": "and"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "country": {
                      "query": "USA",
                      "operator": "and"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "match": {
                    "city": {
                      "query": "Portland",
                      "operator": "and"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**There is no need to use multiple [`bool/should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause and operator (with match query), in your case.**

Adding a working example

**Search by country**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "country": {
            "query": "USA"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67676851",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "email": "mike@example.com",
          "country": "USA",
          "city": "Portland"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67676851",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "email": "You Can Also",
          "country": "USA",
          "city": "Chicago"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**Search by city:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "city": {
            "query": "Portland"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67676851",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6931471,
        "_source": {
          "email": "mike@example.com",
          "country": "USA",
          "city": "Portland"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**Search by city and country:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "city": "Portland"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "country": "USA"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67676851",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.8754687,
        "_source": {
          "email": "mike@example.com",
          "country": "USA",
          "city": "Portland"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason I'm using multiple bool/should is because I have multiple other conditions/fields to search for besides country and city.

Comment: Oh, one more thing. I forgot to mention that it can always be the case to have multiple cities selected and only one country, for example. In this case the `must` doesn't work and `should` should be used.

Comment: @Cosmin in the second query, in one `bool/should` clause you are searching for documents having `country: USA` and in the second `bool/should` clause you are searching for documents having both `country:USA` and `city: Portland`. Since. both the documents have USA in them, so naturally both the documents will return.

Comment: @Cosmin can you please explain what exactly is your requirement? Otherwise, the queries which I gave in my answer above, works fine for your 3 cases

Comment: To put it simple, I want to have an `AND` relation between filters and an `OR` relation inside the options of a single filter.